# How to scrape all events location using python and beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** the location of places where the events have occurred.

link : http://www.globalbigdataconference.com/events.html

The issue is my code returns only 6 location initially and in website you need to click on show more to view more historical records. Is there a way to fetch all the records.

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.globalbigdataconference.com/events.html"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

event_locations = soup.find_all('article', class_= 'clearfix b-m10')
for event_loc in event_locations:
print(event_loc.text)
```

Output:

```
Santa Clara
Santa Clara
Boston
Seattle
Santa Clara
Boston
```

I want to fetch all the locations using the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code, the "Show more" gets the data from this kind of request:

```
url: '/User/Event/EventList',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: { search: search, EventStatus: EType, City: LType, StartDate: SDate, EndDate: EDate, SortColumn: sortcolumn, SortOrder: sortorder, PageNo: pageno, PageItems: PageItems },
```

Try to get the data from this URL, it will be easier

Comment: If you click on "Show more" button on website more events from past are displayed.

Comment: http://www.globalbigdataconference.com/events.html I am referring to this url. Our urls are slightly different.